# Why is the size of the TabControl buttons different in Windows and Linux?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to get an old .NET program to run in Mono under Linux. It works amazingly well, but one thing is something I have failed to get at. I have a TabControl and the tabs are enlarged to be touch friendly, but the navigation buttons are still small. In Windows I don't get those buttons so it's not a problem there. Is there a way to make them larger or remove them?

[image: Small navigation arrows]

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that it's not possible. But there is a workaround. When running on Unix we can reduce the font size of the tab bar so that we don't have the navigation buttons. Not a perfect solution, but it works for this.

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
{
    this.tabControl.Font = new Font("Arial", 17F, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabappearance?view=netframework-3.5) property of the TabControl to FlatButtons. This will remove the navigation buttons and make the tabs themselves clickable:

```
tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
```

Alternatively, you can control it yourself with DrawMode.

```
myTabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
myTabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl_DrawItem);

private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
    TabPage page = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
    Rectangle rect = tabControl.GetTabRect(e.Index);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect );
    g.DrawString(tabPage.Text, tabControl.Font, Brushes.Black, tabRect.X + 10, tabRect.Y + 6);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Well, not quite. "'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' does not contain a definition for 'Appearance' and no extension method 'Appearance' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I may be in the wrong version. Do you have a chance to share an example from your code? It was supposed to include it according to the instructions, I'm sorry. Maybe changing the DrawMode could also be a solution. I edited my answer.

Comment: @liftarn - [`System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.Appearance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.appearance?view=netframework-1.1) existed as far back as .NET Framework 1.1, and still exists in [4.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.appearance?view=netframework-4.8.1)  What version + UI framework are you using?

Comment: @dbc It uses .NET 3.5, but targets the Congatec QSeven.